# How to determine programmatically whether team project has sharepoint portal configured?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-sdk, team-project

In VS.Net 2010 Beta 2: when a team project gets created the wizard offers a choice of whether or not to configure the project's Sharepoint portal. How can I determine **programmatically** whether a team project has a portal configured. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the url?  The default URL for the portal is http://serverName/sites/teamProjectName/default.aspx, rigth? If so, use this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("sharepointURL");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   // Do logic here.
}
```